# choose plus/minus icon?

Tags: visualforce, css, stylesheets

Currently I'm using expand/collapse icons as shown below in the screen shot, but I'm looking to find plus/minus icon where can i find that in salesforce?

```
 .showDetail {
       background: transparent url('/img/alohaSkin/twisty_sprite.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
    }
    .hideDetail {
       background: transparent url('/img/alohaSkin/twisty_sprite.png') 0 -11px no-repeat;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Best practice: You shouldn't ever use Salesforce's images. You should have your own images in Static Resources (even if they are originally borrowed from Salesforce) and reference those in your VF pages. `'/img/alohaSkin/twisty_sprite.png'`

Comment: abuHamzah  You could use your own images in static resources and access them in a VF file. i think there are quite a bit of images available on the net. Using static resource would make sense as mentioned by markPond its not a best practice to use salesforce images

Comment: Not what you're asking, but from a UX point of view I would probably redirect to a new page, rather than use the expand/collapse. Ie put a hyperlink on CustomerNumber that directs to a page showing orders for that customer. This is my subjective opinion.

Answer (score 2):

If you are open to [Bootstrap Glyphicons](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_comp_glyphs.asp):

- **Show Detail**

  - You *have* `glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right` [[example](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_glyph_chevron-right&stacked=h)]
  - You *want* `glyphicon glyphicon-plus` [[example](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_glyph_plus&stacked=h)]
- **Hide Detail**

  - You *have* `glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down` [[example](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_glyph_chevron-down&stacked=h)]
  - You *want* `glyphicon glyphicon-minus` [[example](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_glyph_minus&stacked=h)]

Comment: Except he wants the plus and minus ones, so instead of the chevron ones, he'd want glyphicon-minus and glyphicon-plus ;)

Comment: @cricketlang Good eye. Haha. Second and third on the list, so they're way easier to spot!

Comment: I'm not open to bootstrap :)

Comment: Don't need bootstrap at all. Glyphicons are fonts. Can just put the font into a static resource and reference it in your .showDetal class.